# Single user with multiple databases in Plesk 11

Tags: mysql, plesk, centos6

I am running Centos6 with Plesk 11 and I am trying to assign a single user to have access to multiple databases. I am following the instructions given here: http://kb.parallels.com/en/115783

When I run the command GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `newdb`.* TO 'olduser'@'%'; from the SQL tab in phpmyadmin, I am getting the following error:

## 1044 - Access denied for user 'openemm2'@'%' to database 'openemm_cms'

openemm2 is the username I have assigned to this database -- why the error and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution to this. I had to log into the mysql> prompt using:

```
mysql -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow`
```

This allowed me access to run the command. I have also discovered one can accomplish the same thing through the phpmyadmin panel access through the database servers link from the servers tab in Plesk 11. This is where you find the master phpmyadmin where you can access ALL of your databases rather than the individual access phpmyadmin you get through the database link in the websites & domains tab.